# How to find number of decimal digits for currency in python?

Tags: python

I need to find a number of decimal digits for currency (e.g. 2 for USD, 0 for yen).

I can do it based on locale:

```py
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_us')
print(locale.localeconv()['frac_digits']) # 2
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'ja')
print(locale.localeconv()['frac_digits']) # 0
```

Is it possible to get the same given currency not locale?

Comment: The short answer is "no".  The currency attributes are an aspect of locale.

Comment: Formatting information is associated with locales. You want to be able to get the locale given a currency name, e.g. yen => ja, usd => en_us, etc.?

Comment: What do you mean?  What is the basis for making the decision?

Comment: @Barmar yes, it would be an answer if no other ways possible

Comment: I don't think it's possible, since it's not unique. E.g. there are many locales that use Euro as the currency.

Comment: @Barmar you are right. But I am sure there should be a way to do it. It is possible in `dart` and `js`. I need this function to work with Stripe (where all the payments presented in the currency’s smallest unit (e.g. $10 presented as 1000). I can not believe it is necessary to keep a dictionary for this purpose in python.

Answer (score 0):

I've found this way:

```
import babel.numbers
print(babel.numbers.get_currency_precision('USD'))
print(babel.numbers.get_currency_precision('JPY'))
```

Needs `Babel` library installed.